# Upload PHP não funciona

Tags: php, upload

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer a função de upload de arquivo via PHP utilzando o codigo abaixo:

```
  if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']))
        {            
            $diretorio = "D:/wamp64/www/revi/arquivos/postagens/".$postagem; 
            if(!is_dir($diretorio))
            {
                mkdir("D:/wamp64/www/revi/arquivos/postagens/".$postagem , 0777);
                $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];  
                for ($k = 0; $k < count($arquivo['name']); $k++)
                {       
                    $destino = $diretorio."/".$arquivo['name'][$k];                 
                    if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $diretorio)) 
                    {
                        echo "MOVEUUUUUU<br>"; 
                    }                                
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "não moveu! <br>";
                        echo $_FILES["arquivo"]["error"];
                    }
                }      
            }
```

E meu form está assim

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="arquivos[]" multiple/>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

Mas simplesmente não dá certo. O echo do `$FILES["arquivo"]["error"]` retorna 0 como se tivesse feito o upload com sucesso, mas vou na pasta e não tem nada lá. O que está faltando para dar certo?

Obrigado!

Comment: acontece o "MOVEUUUU<br>"?

Comment: Não acontece. Ele mostra o "Não moveu" e o número 0 na linha de baixo.

Comment: A pasta ela cria com todas as permissões OK, mas sem nenhum arquivo dentro. Como consigo ver este log?

Comment: Mais uma observação: sempre que fizer caminhos múltiplos, observe o 3º parâmetro, o recursive em mkdir("D:/wamp64/www/revi/arquivos/postagens/".$postagem , 0777); - e note que o 2o parâmetro é ignorado no Windows. E cheque o valor de $postagens para ver se está certa a pasta.

Comment: Eu fiz umas mudanças aqui e está dando o seguinte erro:
move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Comment: Você errou a variavel dentro de `(move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $diretorio)`, a correta seria `, $destino);`, veja a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois erros:

1. Você colocou a variavel $diretorio ao invés de $destino aqui `move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $diretorio)`
2. o is_dir deveria ser checado apenas na parte do mkdir
3. **Extra**: não vejo necessidade de usar 0777 (no Windows não faz diferença, mas se em produção for um servidor unix-like isto poderá ser um problema)
4. **Extra**: não tem porque reescrever o caminho todo no `mkdir`, aproveite a variavel que já usou

> **Nota importante**: `$FILES["arquivo"]["error"]` não garante o "upload", garante apenas que chegou no servidor na pasta `./tmp` do teu servidor, o `move_uploaded_file` faz mover do `./tmp` para a pasta desejada.

Para corrigir faça isto:

```
if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']))
{            
    $diretorio = "D:/wamp64/www/revi/arquivos/postagens/".$postagem;

    //Verifica se a pasta já existe ou tenta cria-la
    $checarPasta = is_dir($diretorio) ? true : mkdir($diretorio, 0777);

    //Se não existir exibe um erro
    if(!$checarPasta)
    {
        echo 'Não pode criar ou acessar a pasta: ', $diretorio;
    }
    else
    {
        $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];  

        for ($k = 0; $k < count($arquivo['name']); $k++)
        {       
            $destino = $diretorio."/".$arquivo['name'][$k];

            if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $destino)) 
            {
                echo "MOVEUUUUUU<br>"; 
            }                                
            else 
            {
                echo "não moveu! <br>";
                echo $_FILES["arquivo"]["error"];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Guilherme. Obrigado pelas dicas, assim poderei aperfeiçoar meus futuros códigos.